# What is in a buffer generate with recvfrom at UDP in C?

Tags: c, linux, udp

I work on a library to parse connection information from a satellite modem. It sends this information as an UDP package over the network, which I receive with `recvfrom()`.

What information do I get via the `buffer` parameter of [`recvfrom()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recvfrom.html)? Is it only the UDP message field, or do I get more information about the UDP package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer will only receive the payload data of the packet. Headers are not included.